# how to solve issues between actiobar and toolbar in android in different versions of android

Tags: android

i finished my project .but it only runs on lollipop and marshmallow.it does not runs in kitkat and older versions due to action bar and toolbar prblm.if adjust the theme ,some times it shows me two action bars on top.i m new to android.anybody help me to finish tis completely.its my first project given to me.thank you ...i m running out of time...i m posting my one sample activity...

```
            `<activity android:name=".anims.AnimHome"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"  />'
```

my toolbar theme is

```
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


'public class AnimHome extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private ProgressDialog loadDialog;
private JSONArray _myResponse;
public ActionBar ab;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.anim_home);
    inilizeProgressDialog();
    drawerLayout();
  }
private void drawerLayout() {

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    try {

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    if (drawer != null) {
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    }
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
```

}'

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the app using API level 8. Level 8 goes on 95% of android devices. Also you can check your manifest and try to set your "miniSdk to 8" "targetSdk to 18" and "maxSdk to 24".
You want to search your manifest for something that looks like this

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />`

Comment: thank you lot for ur reply...but i changed  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item> to  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>..in styles.xml..which solves my problem